# Java Comparable Class - Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java

I'm writing an isometric game that renders objects based on their Y coordinate, using a comparable class, sorting by their Y value, which changes. I am getting the error "Comparison method violates its general contract!" and have read about how to return a negative number, 0, or a positive number so I have implemented this:

```
public boolean equals(Entity e) {
    if ((e.y-y)==0)
        return (e.id == id);
    return (e.y == y);
}

public int compareTo(Entity e) {
    if ((e.y-y)==0)
        return (e.id - id);
    return (int) (e.y - y); // Render order by y coordinate
}
```

But I'm still getting the error. Is the sorting not going to work if the values change or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: What type is your `y` field?

Comment: y is of type float

Comment: There are numerous questions about that exception message already. Search before posting. Demonstrate that your question is not a duplicate of one of the previous questions.

Comment: Yes and I have read up on the general contract, but I just failed to see that the way I was doing it would return inconsistent results. However, I posted here because I was mainly asking about the constant re-calculation of the value that I'm using to sort and if this, in itself, would violate the contract.

Answer (score 7):

The `equals` method is not involved in the contract, so we can ignore it.

I suspect that the problem is caused by integer overflow.  The problem is that `x - y` does not always give you a positive answer if `x > y` and a negative number if `x < y`.  If the difference between the numbers is large enough, then the express `x - y` will overflow and the result will have the wrong sign.

If that is the problem, then the simple solution is to use `Integer.compare(x, y)` instead of `x - y`

Another possibility is that the entities are being mutated at the same time as you are (for example) sorting them.

---

> Float.compare(x, y) has worked much better.

I'd assumed that `x` and `y` were `int`.  If they are `float` then the true cause of the problem is harder to understand.  Either way, using `Float.compare(x, y)` is a better solution.

But if `x` and `y` are actually `int`, then using `Float.compare(x, y)` will give you *incorrect* answers for some `x` and `y` values.  For close values of `x` and `y` with large enough magnitudes, the `int` to `float` conversion will lose precision, and `Float.compare` will say they are equal.

Comment: You are completely right. I don't know why I didn't see that before. The y values can both be positive or both be negative or one of each and would give different results. Float.compare(x, y) has worked much better. Thanks so much for your help!